# Unable to create web service using wsdl2java in CXF using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create a web service from a WSDL file.

I am using Eclipse 4.6.2 (Neon 2), with Apache CXF 3.2.0 and Tomcat 9.

After I create a dynamic web project, I copy my WSDL file to the `WebContent` folder, and use it to generate a top-down Java bean Web Service. I want to create a test web client so I set the sliders to "Start service" and "Start client", with the options to publish and monitor the WS both checked. Then I click Finish. After a while, the process would terminate with an error. This is what I get on the console:

```
Loading FrontEnd jaxws ...
Loading DataBinding jaxb ...
wsdl2java -d C:\Users\USER\workspace\TestWS\.cxftmp/src -classdir C:\Users\USER\workspace\TestWS\build\classes -p http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/=com.dematic.ndcwebservices -impl -validate -exsh false -dns true -dex true -wsdlLocation file:/C:/Users/USER/workspace/TestWS/WebContent/ndcwebservices_single.wsdl -verbose -defaultValues -fe jaxws -db jaxb -wv 1.1 file:/C:/Users/USER/workspace/TestWS/WebContent/ndcwebservices_single.wsdl
wsdl2java - Apache CXF 3.2.0

Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}Start cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}StopAci cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}CheckIsConnected cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}StartOrder cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}CancelOrder cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}CancelOrderByCarrier cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}SendAck cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}SendNack cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}UpdatePriority cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}UpdateParameter cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}ReadParameters cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}ReadGlobalParameters cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Sep 20, 2017 5:53:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/}WriteGlobalParameter cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
```

This is part of the WSDL file I am using. In full it is 616 lines long, I tried to omit what I think is irrelevant to the question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="AciService" targetNamespace="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="CustomBinding_IAciService_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NDC.WebServices.DataContracts"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NDC.ACI"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
            ...
            <xs:element name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="response" nillable="true" type="tns:NDCServiceResp"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:complexType name="NDCServiceResp">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IsError" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Message" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="NDCServiceResp" nillable="true" type="tns:NDCServiceResp"/>
            ...
        </xs:schema>
        ...
    </wsdl:types>
    ...
    <wsdl:portType name="IAciService">
        <wsdl:operation name="Start">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/Start" name="StartRequest" message="tns:StartRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/StartResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="StopAci">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/StopAci" name="StopAciRequest" message="tns:StopAciRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/StopAciResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CheckIsConnected">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/CheckIsConnected" name="CheckIsConnectedRequest" message="tns:CheckIsConnectedRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/CheckIsConnectedResponse" name="NDCServiceIsConnectedResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceIsConnectedResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="StartOrder">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/StartOrder" name="StartOrderRequest" message="tns:StartOrderRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/StartOrderResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CancelOrder">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/CancelOrder" name="CancelOrderRequest" message="tns:CancelOrderRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/CancelOrderResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CancelOrderByCarrier">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/CancelOrderByCarrier" name="CancelOrderByCarrierRequest" message="tns:CancelOrderByCarrierRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/CancelOrderByCarrierResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SendAck">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/SendAck" name="SendAckRequest" message="tns:SendAckRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/SendAckResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SendNack">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/SendNack" name="SendNackRequest" message="tns:SendNackRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/SendNackResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="UpdatePriority">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/UpdatePriority" name="UpdatePriorityRequest" message="tns:UpdatePriorityRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/UpdatePriorityResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="UpdateParameter">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/UpdateParameter" name="UpdateParameterRequest" message="tns:UpdateParameterRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/UpdateParameterResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="ReadParameters">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/ReadParameters" name="ReadParametersRequest" message="tns:ReadParametersRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/ReadParametersResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="ReadGlobalParameters">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/ReadGlobalParameters" name="ReadGlobalParametersRequest" message="tns:ReadGlobalParametersRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/ReadGlobalParametersResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="WriteGlobalParameter">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/WriteGlobalParameter" name="WriteGlobalParameterRequest" message="tns:WriteGlobalParameterRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/WriteGlobalParameterResponse" name="NDCServiceResponse" message="tns:NDCServiceResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="CustomBinding_IAciService" type="tns:IAciService">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#CustomBinding_IAciService_policy"/>
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="Start">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/Start" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="StartRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:StartRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:StartRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="StopAci">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/StopAci" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="StopAciRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:StopAciRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:StopAciRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CheckIsConnected">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/CheckIsConnected" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="CheckIsConnectedRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:CheckIsConnectedRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:CheckIsConnectedRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceIsConnectedResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="StartOrder">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/StartOrder" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="StartOrderRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:StartOrderRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:StartOrderRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CancelOrder">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/CancelOrder" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="CancelOrderRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:CancelOrderRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:CancelOrderRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CancelOrderByCarrier">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/CancelOrderByCarrier" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="CancelOrderByCarrierRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:CancelOrderByCarrierRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:CancelOrderByCarrierRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SendAck">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/SendAck" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="SendAckRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:SendAckRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:SendAckRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SendNack">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/SendNack" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="SendNackRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:SendNackRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:SendNackRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="UpdatePriority">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/UpdatePriority" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="UpdatePriorityRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:UpdatePriorityRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:UpdatePriorityRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="UpdateParameter">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/UpdateParameter" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="UpdateParameterRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:UpdateParameterRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:UpdateParameterRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="ReadParameters">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/ReadParameters" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="ReadParametersRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:ReadParametersRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:ReadParametersRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="ReadGlobalParameters">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/ReadGlobalParameters" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="ReadGlobalParametersRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:ReadGlobalParametersRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:ReadGlobalParametersRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="WriteGlobalParameter">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.dematic.com/ndcwebservices/IAciService/WriteGlobalParameter" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="WriteGlobalParameterRequest">
                <soap12:header message="tns:WriteGlobalParameterRequest_Headers" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:WriteGlobalParameterRequest_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="NDCServiceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="AciService">
        <wsdl:port name="CustomBinding_IAciService" binding="tns:CustomBinding_IAciService">
            <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8779/ndcwebservices"/>
            <wsa10:EndpointReference>
                <wsa10:Address>http://localhost:8779/ndcwebservices</wsa10:Address>
            </wsa10:EndpointReference>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

When I validate this WSDL in Eclipse, I get 11 errors, all with the following message:

```
The name 'NDCServiceResponse' specified for this output element is not unique. The name of an output element must be unique from the names of all other inputs and output elements defined in the 'IAciService' port type.
```

Are these two related? What should I change in the WSDL to ensure that I can get a very basic web service running?

(Edit: If anyone is willing to help me by replicating this problem, I can provide the full WSDL file)

Comment: I could have a look at the WSDL if you would place the full code here.

Comment: @Namphibian I'd love to but I exceeded the character limit when I tried to post it here